# How to change one image when multiple areas can be clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image on an expandable chat window.  Basic plus and minus sign, but what I am getting hung up on is that you can click on two different spots to open the window.  Right now when you click on the icon the image will change but if you click on the header bar of the chat window or the persons name and expand the window the icon stays the same and then gets out of sync. I feel like there has to be a solid way to include all those options into one method but cannot figure it out.  It seems that just having it trigger on an "< a >" click is the answer but I cannot get that worded correctly to work.

My jquery method is this

```
$(document).on('click','.chatWindowStatusImageToggle', function(){
$(this).attr('src', function (index, currentSource) {
  return currentSource == '/img/icons/icon-minimize.png' ? '/img/icons/icon-plus.png' : '/img/icons/icon-minimize.png';
 });   
});
```

the two  tags are below (the first one has the img src in it and is the one that changes the image when clicked). They are inside the div along with a dropdown that comes before them.

```
<div class="chat-controls">

...

  <a class="chatWindowStatus myCollapse"  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#chatAccordion" href="#chat-{{ $thread->id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="chat-{{ $thread->id }}" data-thread-id="{{$thread->id}}"><img class="chatWindowStatusImageToggle ...

  <a class="myCollapse chat-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#chatAccordion" href="#chat-{{ $thread->id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="chat-{{ $thread->id }}" data-thread-id="{{$thread->id}}" style="width:65%; float:left;">...
```

Thanks so much for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up solving this was adding the image swap into the actual click function that was opening and closing the window.  The original code was altered a little by creating an id for just the "< img..." and then placed inside that method.

```
$(document).on('click', ...

$('#chatWindowStatusToggle').attr('src', function (index, currentSource) {
  return currentSource == '/img/icons/icon-minimize.png' ? '/img/icons/icon-plus.png' : '/img/icons/icon-minimize.png';
});  

...
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want both  elements to fire the same function, just give them both the same class. And then set the click-event on that class.

```
<a class="fireFunction chatWindowStatus myCollapse>...</a>
<a class="fireFunction myCollapse chat-title>...</a>
```

and

```
$(document).on('click','.fireFunction ', function(){
  ...
});
```

Comment: actually I tried that first and it did not work.  What I ended up doing was adding it into the click function that was closing the window itself.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is, that you have to change your function as $(this) is returning different things for both classes.